# query one row form multiple same row for mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have 4 tables such as roomtype,hotel,available and rimage.Roomtype have 4 rows for room.Hotel have one row.Available have 4 rows for today's date.
But rimage many row for one roomtype's row.

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM roomtype
  LEFT JOIN hotel
    ON roomtype.hid = hotel.hid
  LEFT JOIN available
    ON roomtype.rid = available.rid
  LEFT JOIN rimage
    ON roomtype.rid = rimage.rid
 WHERE available.adt = '$today'
```

When these query run,I get many rows from rimage.But I want to get only one row for each one roomtype's row.How can I write my query for these solution.

Comment: *But I want to get only one row for each one roomtype's row* ... which one?

Comment: use group by with hid

Comment: roomtype table have 4 rows for four rooms.I joined roomtype and rimage in my query.I have one rimage'row for one room.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM roomtype 
LEFT JOIN hotel ON roomtype.hid = hotel.hid 
LEFT JOIN available ON roomtype.rid = available.rid 
INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(rid) FROM rimage WHERE roomtype.rid = rimage.rid) b ON roomtype.rid = b.rid  
where available.adt = '$today'
```

OR this if roomtype not must have a rimage

```
SELECT * 
FROM roomtype 
LEFT JOIN hotel ON roomtype.hid = hotel.hid 
LEFT JOIN available ON roomtype.rid = available.rid 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MIN(rid) FROM rimage WHERE roomtype.rid = rimage.rid) b ON roomtype.rid = b.rid  
where available.adt = '$today'
```